# Providing less Aguments

Tags: arguments

I have this code:

```
var obj;
if (!instance_exists(oTextbox)) {
    obj=instance_create(0,0,oTextbox)
    obj.textfont=argument0
    obj.text[0]=argument1 
    obj.text[1]=argument2
    obj.text[2]=argument3
    obj.text[3]=""
}
```

Its a simple way to draw text, but when I call it with less arguments I get a compile error(expected 4 arguments provided 3), 
I just want a way to be able to provide less arguments so the code will ignore if I provided less arguments and will just go to the last line

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: Java Eclipse, using to make a app on adroid

Comment: Your question is vague, I can't understand it. Anyway that doesn't look like java, it look more like javascript (that was the language i thought it was before reading "compile error").

Comment: When you call **what**? You've shown nothing you're calling except `instance_exists` and `instance_create`. You need to [edit] your question, make it more clear what you're asking, provide the **relevant** code, and at least add a tag for the language you're using if you want help here.

Answer (score 0):

Well not very sure what you mean exactly, you can try [`varargs`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) to pass variable number of arguments and check length when using them:

```
public void DrawText(Object... args)
{
    var obj;
    if (!instance_exists(oTextbox)) {
        obj=instance_create(0,0,oTextbox);
        int len=args.Length;

        obj.textfont = args[0].toString();
        obj.text[0] = args[1].toString();

        if(len>2){
            obj.text[1] = args[2].toString();
        }

        if(len>3){
            obj.text[2] = args[3].toString();;
        }

        if(len>4){
            obj.text[3] = args[4].toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Supposing you will always pass at least two values, one for `textfont` and one for `text[0]`.